# if each figure is visible within a scrollabe div

Tags: jquery

I have a list of items within a scrollable (jQuery tools)...
It's shows 3 items/figures at a time, when clicking the next button, it's shows the 3 next...

The thing im trying to do, is that i want do for example call a webservice, when the items that are showed within the scrollable area, the items that arent showed in the scrollable area, should do nothing - Only when clicking the next button, and the 3 next items are showed...

My HTML output looks like this:

```
<div id="adbelt">
<div class="ad-container">
    <div id="prevnext">
        <a class="next carouselbutton"><span>next</span></a>
        <a class="prev carouselbutton"><span>prev</span></a>
    </div>
    <div id="belt">
        <div class="scrollable" id="scrollable">
            <div class="items">
                <figure>
                    <a target="_blank" title="http://www.dis-play.dk/" href="http://www.dis-play.dk/">

                    </a>
                    <figcaption>
                        <span>Skarp</span>
                        <div class="fig-text">og lige til</div>
                    </figcaption>
                    <input type="hidden" name="ctl10$phadlist_0$hiddenFieldAdGuid" id="ctl10_phadlist_0_hiddenFieldAdGuid" value="B2A276D78E764528900B723F144117A7" />
                </figure>

                <figure>
                    <a target="_blank" title="DIS/Play" href="http://www.dis-play.dk">
                        <img src="~/media/DISPLAY/Default/defaultAdImage.ashx" class="slide-banner" alt="Kaffe" width="300" height="150" />
                    </a>
                    <figcaption>
                        <span>Forbrugsforeningen 2</span>
                        <div class="fig-text">har det hele</div>
                    </figcaption>
                    <input type="hidden" name="ctl10$phadlist_1$hiddenFieldAdGuid" id="ctl10_phadlist_1_hiddenFieldAdGuid" value="75011C876D04465D865B34FA6DC2CBE3" />
                </figure>

                <figure>
                    <a target="_blank" title="http://www.dis-play.dk/" href="http://www.dis-play.dk/">

                    </a>
                    <figcaption>
                        <span>Skarp</span>
                        <div class="fig-text">og lige til</div>
                    </figcaption>
                    <input type="hidden" name="ctl10$phadlist_2$hiddenFieldAdGuid" id="ctl10_phadlist_2_hiddenFieldAdGuid" value="B2A276D78E764528900B723F144117A7" />
                </figure>

                <figure>
                    <figcaption>
                        <span></span>
                        <div class="fig-text"></div>
                    </figcaption>
                    <input type="hidden" name="ctl10$phadlist_3$hiddenFieldAdGuid" id="ctl10_phadlist_3_hiddenFieldAdGuid" value="BE7DA9601D4840B981A1E5305E01786F" />
                </figure>

                <figure>
                    <a target="_blank" title="DIS/Play" href="http://www.dis-play.dk">
                        <img src="~/media/DISPLAY/Default/defaultAdImage.ashx" class="slide-banner" alt="Kaffe" width="300" height="150" />
                    </a>
                    <figcaption>
                        <span>Forbrugsforeningen 2</span>
                        <div class="fig-text">har det hele</div>
                    </figcaption>
                    <input type="hidden" name="ctl10$phadlist_4$hiddenFieldAdGuid" id="ctl10_phadlist_4_hiddenFieldAdGuid" value="75011C876D04465D865B34FA6DC2CBE3" />
                </figure>

                <figure>



                    <figcaption>
                        <span></span>
                        <div class="fig-text"></div>
                    </figcaption>
                    <input type="hidden" name="ctl10$phadlist_5$hiddenFieldAdGuid" id="ctl10_phadlist_5_hiddenFieldAdGuid" value="BE7DA9601D4840B981A1E5305E01786F" />
                </figure>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

I've tried this:

```
 $("#belt figure").each(function () {

    if ($(this).filter(':visible')) {
        alert("visible");
        //Do something, like calling a webservice
    } else {
        alert("not visible");
        //Dont call webservice
    }

});
```

I've tried looking at the jquery.appear plugin, but it doesnt seem to support the thing i want?

Comment: One thing I've noticed in your HTML is that all the `<figure>` elements are visible. In other words, none of them have `style=display:none`, or whatever, in order to hide them. Could be a red-herring, but I thought I'd point that out.

Comment: Yeah, i know, and that is the problem, that's why I cant do it with :visible - So I need somekind of method that can check if the figure elements are visible within a specific viewport of a div - Ex: #belt is 980px wide

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could probably just loop through only visible figures if that's the only ones you are interested in

```
$("#belt figure:visible").each({...});
```

Or if you're looking to do something with each figure based on their visibility, I think you're looking for the `is()` method:

```
if ($(this).is(":visible")) {
    //Do something
} else {
    //Do something else
}
```

**edit:** I now see that you're trying something else. If you want to see if it's visible within an area, you need to do something else. `:visible` will be true if the element isn't `display:none` or `visibility:hidden`.

So you need to check the height of the scrollable area and the `scrollTop`, then check the `offset` of each figure against those numbers to see if it's visible

**edit2:** Is it something [like this](http://jsbin.com/icuber/edit#javascript,html,live) you had in mind?

Comment: The problem is that all figures are visible, none of them have the display:none - So I cant use :visible  :(

Comment: @NickyChristensen Added a working example to my answer, that I think might be something along the lines of what you're looking for.

Comment: Yeah, it's exactly like that, however, I just need it in a horisontal state, instead of vertical...

Comment: @NickyChristensen Then just switch `offset().top` with `offset().left` and `scrollTop` with `scrollLeft` (: